# HTTP reading and rewriting bytes

Tags: scala, http, encoding, playframework-2.0

I am getting a blob of binary data by executing a command-line program. This blob can be decoded by the same program.

I would like to send this binary data in a HTTP response. For that I use the `"application/octet-stream"` mime-type (I also tried "text/plain"). But when the client gets the data on the other end, it is not readable anymore. The format has changed somehow.

Here is my Scala code (but I think it is a generic question):

```
val command = s"samtools view -h $testbam $region"
val res: String = command.!!    // Gets the stdout as string

Result(
  header = ResponseHeader(200, Map.empty),
  body = HttpEntity.Strict(ByteString(res), Some("application/octet-stream"))
)
```

The same command, run on the command-line, can be decoded properly. But the result of a "curl" here, although it does return a bunch of unreadable symbols, cannot be decoded.

Sending the same data in its readable (uncompressed) form goes through properly without losing content or formatting.

What kind of characters conversion am I missing ? Any encoding to specify ?

Edit: Play 2.5.0

Comment: Have you tried by getting the data as inputStream and stream it directly to the client: Ok.stream(Enumerator.fromStream(streamFromProgram)) ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but `Ok.stream` does not compile ("cannot resolve symbol stream").

Comment: I'm using play 2.4 and this seems to work: Future(Ok.stream(Enumerator.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream("This is my data".getBytes))))

Comment: I have 2.5 and it does not :( I should have mentioned the play version, sorry.